# Can we use Dzikir instead of mantras to make meditation more Islamic?

Tags: practical-islam, prophet-muhammad, medical, makruh, health

I use meditation for reaching the very productive and creative 4th state of consciousness (body fully at deep rest with slow deep breathing but mind fully alert).  I had been using Sanskrit mantras as focal points to get the mind into a thoughtless state.  The mantras don't mean anything, just sounds repetitively uttered to suit this purpose.

Recently I have substituted dzikir such as "Subahan Allah" to be used in place of the traditional mantra "Shon Laman".

Is their anything makruh (questionable) in doing this?

We know that our prophet (pbuh) used to go to the cave outside Mecca and spend many hours in meditation prior to receiving his first revelation, but we have little details on this meditation.

Comment: Is your question is whether replacing chants from a vedic religion with Islamic dhikr is makruh? If so, you're basically asking whether replacing shirk/imitating kuffar with dhikr is makruh, which sounds strange to ask.

Comment: If the mantras have no meaning, I don't see how we can conclude it is shirk or imitating shirk.  The reason I ask is if this is outside the normal intended use of Dzikir. iow I am doing it for health benefits and not solely for worship purposes.  Sort of like performing salat for exercise purposes in addition to worship.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

brother 
As salaam alaikum 
Meditation is  alleviating all thoughts. Ability to focus on a single thought is also its equivalent. 
For Muslims the best form of meditation is already assigned by Allah .  Salaah. The prayers. 
In salaah you get connected to Allah while He communicates to you. This is not uncommon . Most of us know this.

However the point I want to make is something else. 
Have you ever considered that there are occasion for all of us where we are able to focus on a particular matter to an extent that we are completely oblivious to all the things happening around us. 
These are matters of extreme emergencies.

Let me give a couple of examples.
Your family doctor , whom you trust most, giving you an advice or a prescription for your coronory heart disease. 
Nobody has to tell you to pay attention to the doctors advice. 
You do that since you know it's worth.

If you are crossing a road and all of a sudden you see a speedy vehicle in your direction, may be only a couple of meters away, you of course go thoughtless here.

You see in these instances we we're able to practise the highest form of meditation without any training.

For a Muslim the life of this world itself is a state of emergency. 
So when he stands in salaah he is able to focus on what he reads since he knows the value of the advice given. 
He is able to focus also because he is in awe of the advice giver.(Allah) . This point needs a separate discussion.

So salaah is the best form of meditation as well. 
Of course the movements are also placed in it for additional benefits for it's readers. However the crux is the guidance for both worlds given through the Qur'an.

Regards 
Rehan